# How long does broadcast exist?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, broadcast

I have an button at my page. When a user clicks on my button, the following code Is executed:

```
as.controller('CustSummary', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $routeParams, $location)
{
         var loadAbbDetails = function()
        {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('loadDetails');
        }

        $scope.viewAbbDetails = function()
        {
            loadAbbDetails();
        }
}
```

I have attached at listener for "loadDetails" In another controller:

```
as.controller('CustomerCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $routeParams, $location)
{
  var loadDetails = function()
  {
     $scope.include = 'partials/customer/customerabbdetails.html';
  };

   $scope.$on("loadDetails",function(event,args) {
      loadDetails();
   });
}
```

I just wonder for how long this listener "exists"? Is It destroyed when loadDetails() Is fired?

Comment: The listener will stay and listen for further `loadDetails` events even after executing.

Comment: @Fissio: Okey. Because I have tried to use this In another controller like this:  http://pastebin.com/jwYgdBcE but nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have defined the event on $rootScope, you should be listening the same on $rootScope instead of $scope. Also, as you have defined the listener on $scope, the listener is destroyed as on as the scope of the containing controller is destroyed , .i.e., `CustomerCtrl`.

Comment: Thank you. I have changed that now. But how can I trigger the loadDetails() function again from a another controller?

Comment: By again using - $rootScope.$broadcast('loadDetails'); and if you use $rootScope.on, then it will be listened from every where

Comment: When an event is broadcasted from `$rootScope` you are not obligated to listen on `$rootScope` - `$scope.$on` works just as well. Broadcast is propagated downward on scope hierarchy. @Bryan

Comment: The answer is incorrect. `$rootScope.$broadcast` implies that you listen on root and all nested scopes. Otherwise `$rootScope.$emit` is used.

Comment: When did I mention that it does not listen on $scope. It does, I am just saying that if you will listen on $rootScope, you don't have to re define the listener again and again